# Perform Action after UIAlertView is showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am uploading a picture to a server. I am using a UIAlertView, AlertView1, which asks the user if he/she wants to upload the picture. If Yes, a second alertview, AlertView2 will show with a progress bar and disappear after the upload is complete.

So, once the user clicks on Yes in AlertView1, I call show AlertView2 and call the method [self uploadPhoto]. So the problem comes that even before AlertView2 has time to show up, the CPU intensive uploadPhoto is running and it delays the AlertView2 from showing up for several seconds. It seems like the AlertView2 finally shows a ways through the uploading process.

How do I start the uploading process only once AlertView2 has shown?

Here is the code

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      //Detectss AlertView1's buttonClick 
      [self.alertView2 show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

     //Launches when AlertView1 is dismissed
     [self UploadPhoto]
 }

 -(void)uploadPhoto
{
     //CPU/Network Intensive Code to Upload a photo to a server.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your controller as the delegate of the second alert view, and upload the photo when you receive the didPresentAlertView: message from your second alert.

Comment: thanks! that was dumb of me not to look at the delegate methods. X_X I just relied on the xcode popups of `-(void)alertView...`

Answer (score 0):

Call your method `[self uploadPhoto]` after calling `[self.alertView2 show]` with a timer using -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(uploadPhoto) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

It will call your method after a 3 seconds gap after your alert appears.

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-threading to dispatch `uploadPhoto` to another thread. That way you won't block the main thread while performing costly network operations.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("upload queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [self uploadPhoto];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //dismiss alertview2 here
    });
});
```